# Date Object and UTC Method

Tags: javascript

**Why is this returning the *31st* instead of the *1st*?** As I understand it, the `UTC` method requires 3 parameters ( full year, month, day ), and the day parameter must be an integer between 1 - 31. Because `getDate()` returns with an integer between 0 and 31, I also suspected `0` would be a possibility.

```
firstDay = new Date(Date.UTC( 2011 , 7 , 1 )).getDate(); 
// returns 31 (last day of this month)
```

Let me clarify and say, this is not a special case. With the day parameter as 2, 3, or 4, this will return 1, 2, 3, and so on.

Comment: This looks like a time zone issue. Are you in a time zone west of UTC?

Comment: We are in Central Standard Time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your timezone offset is negative so like -4. So 7/1/2011 at 12:00AM minus 4 hours is 6/31/2011 8:00PM. [Date.UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) takes additional parameters that you can use to pass hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds.

But really, if you don't want the timezone adjustment use `new Date(year, month, day)`

```
firstDay = new Date(2011 , 7 , 1).getDate(); // returns 1 (first day of this month)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am at `(GMT-0700) Pacific Time`.  Here are the results when I conduct the following:

```
new Date( 2011, 7, 1 ); 
// -> Mon Aug 01 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

new Date( Date.UTC( 2011, 7, 1 ) ); 
// -> Sun Jul 31 2011 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

Notice that pulling the UTC time gives me the date/time in my current location, 7 hours prior to the date specified because I'm 7 hours behind Greenwich Mean Time.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for:

```
new Date(Date.UTC(2011, 7, 1) + ((new Date).getTimezoneOffset() / 60) * 3600000).getDate();
```

Explanation:

`(new Date).getTimeZoneOffset(); // will retrieve the timezone offset, (420 in my case PST)`

`offset / 60; // we divide by 60 so we can get the number of hours between UTC and me`

`(offset / 60) * 360000 // is 60 (seconds) * 60 (minutes) * 1000 (ms)`

`+ Date.UTC(2011, 7, 1) // will give us the correct Date always`