# javascript Date.parse and Date.UTC give different results

Tags: javascript, date

Can anyone explain to me why?

```
d = Date.parse('8/15/2012 '+'11:59:45 AM');
alert(d);
alert(Date.UTC(2012, 7, 15, 11, 59, 45));
```

​

Comment: If you are going to use `Date.parse` (which is not a good idea) at least use the format [specified in ES5](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.1.15). Better though to use values and call the Date constructor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date Object and UTC Method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070141/date-object-and-utc-method)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Date.parse assumes local time if not specified.

The UTC one, however, is obviously UTC.

For example, my computer is UTC -5 (well, Chicago CDT actually), so the two timestamps happen to be 5 hours apart for me.

You will get the same thing if you specify UTC:

```
Date.parse('8/15/2012 '+'11:59:45 AM UTC'); //1345031985000
Date.UTC(2012, 7, 15, 11, 59, 45); //1345031985000
```

Answer (score -1):

I'll assume the difference in months was a typo in your question.

Date.parse returns the difference between the date provided and midnight 1 January 1970.

Date.UTC returns the difference between your date and midnight 1 January 1970 **GMT**.

If your timezone is set to GMT (UTC) you should expect to see the same value returned by both calls.

Comment: The months aren't different. `UTC` and other `Date` methods use a 0-based month, but formatted date strings don't.

Comment: Both parse and UTC return a timestamp relative to 1 Jan 1970 UTC.  The difference isn't in the reference point of the timestamp but rather how they interpret the date provided.  parse assumes local time unless told otherwise, whereas UTC uses UTC.  Also, months are 0-indexed, so the 7 for August is correct.